# Printing SQL query output on separate lines

Tags: python, sql

I need to print the result of my SQL query on separate lines as currently it returns as one big long line as shown below.

[image]
[image]

here is the code so far

```
def getdata(name):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('details.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM tbldetails WHERE name = '" + name +"' ")
    result = c.fetchone()
    return(result)
```

The result I am looking for is the outputs to be as follows:

```
value1
value2
value3
```

Comment: Please share the full text that is in the box and explain how you call the function. What are `value1 value2 value3` supposed to be? The values of the fields? Or do you expect them to be values from consecutive records?

Comment: Like... `for k, v in result.items(): print(v)` (To iterate through the columns in the single result row you have captured using `fetchone()`)?. Or... are you wanting to iterate many result rows, in which case `.fetchall()` would be more appropriate.

Comment: If the fields are all strings, then the obvious `'\n'.join(result)` would do the job.  And I see you're using SQLite, so every field is a string.

Comment: Tim Roberts. your solution worked perfectly thank you

Answer (score -1):

you should share the value of the cell that you're fetching to provide more information.

Generally you could either:

1. `.split()` the value on any separator-character.
2. Iterate over the result with `for x in c.execute(...`
3. Or maybe even use `c.fetchall()` and iterate over the list.

Comment: He's getting one record.  It's returning a tuple for the row, as `fetchone` always does.  There's nothing to split.  This answer is not useful.

Comment: @TimRoberts Agreed, the author probably needs to iterate over the tuple's elements and print them each on a single line.